# Writing replace regex in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I have a following kinde of fields:

```
   public static final String "some text1", "Test";
   public static final String "some text2", "test222";
   public static final String "some text3", "someothervalue";
```

I wanted make it like this:

```
   public static final String "some text1";
   public static final String "some text2";
   public static final String "some text3";
```

I'm using like this regEx: ,([^=]*)

[image: Replace screen]
But it is matching first line and the rest of the string with semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this: `(?=,)(.*\n?)(?=;)` which finds starting character with `(?=,)` and ending `(?=;)` and replace it with an empty string.